# How to move the google maps camera only with one fingers?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I am developing google map with flutter web.

The problem that occurred to me is that when I load the web I made into a webview of android or ios, I have to move the map with two fingers.

How do I move the map using one finger?

Comment: This is intended functionality now. They moved to two finger map scrolling/panning so users could scroll past an embedded map. Previously, with one finger scrolling a user could easily get stuck on a map and not be able to scroll away from it without refreshing the page.

Comment: The above being said, I think the setting you are looking for is [gestureHandling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling)

Comment: This is too inconvenient for me. Doesn't a workaround exist?

Comment: You will want to define [gestureHandling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.gestureHandling) in the configuration for where you are calling the map, if you are not doing the config yourself you will have to look into how the config is being done and see if you can add additional configuration. You will need to provide more code in your question if you want more specific help, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.